# is this correct use of pointer and memory allocation

Tags: c, initialization, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

so This is my code that allocate 0th and 2ed string in 2-d array (list of strings, or a bucket) So I like to know did I use correct use of dynamic memory allocation with malloc and realloc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main(){
    
    char **a;
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(*a));
    a = malloc(sizeof(*a)*3);
    a[0] = malloc(sizeof(char ) * 10);
    strcpy(a[0],"hello");
    printf("%s\n",a[0]);
    a[2] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
    strcpy(a[2],"hello hello");
    printf("%s\n",a[2]);
    a[0] = realloc(a[0],18);
    strcpy(a[0],"hello hello hello");
    printf("%s\n",a[0]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I like to knw can I jump from 0th string allocation to 2ed string allocation. is is valid in C/C++

Like first I did

```
a[0] = malloc(sizeof(char ) * 10);
```

then

```
a[2] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
```

missing 1st index allocation like

```
a[1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);//didnt do
```

Comment: This code is not C++, otherwise you would be using the `new[]` operator.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to allocate/free in whatever order you like. No problem with that.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli do I need to free index 2 one time or two times?

Comment: For every allocation there needs to be one free. If you only allocate once you will only need to free it once. If you re-allocate it after freeing then you will need to free it again.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli what about before realloc (to free malloc memory) and after realloc use of free on a[0]

Comment: `realloc` frees current allocation if exists (keeping only the new one), so you only need to free the new one, i.e. the result of `realloc`.

Comment: You can see realloc as the same as doing a free immediately followed by a new malloc.

Comment: As you mention C++, there you would do `std::string s = "Hello";` and can then do `s = "hello hello hello";` to modify the string. The string class will allocate and free itself as needed. (Just to show that C/C++ isn't one language).

Comment: @user786 Alternative to `a[2] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);` that uses the referenced object an not type: `a[2] = malloc(sizeof a[2][0] * 12);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the code is unsafe because the second element stays uninitialized.

At least you should write

```
a[1] = NULL;
```

For example this allows to free the allocated memory in a loop.

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    free( a[i] );
}

free( a );
```

Also this statement

```
a[0] = realloc(a[0],18);
```

is unsafe. You need to use an intermediate pointer like for example

```
char *tmp = realloc(a[0],18);
if ( tmp ) a[0] = tmp;
```

Otherwise a memory leak can occur if the allocation will fail.

And in any case you should check whether allocations were successful.

Comment: `is unsafe. You need to use an intermediate pointer like for example` I dont understand can u explain some more on this

Comment: @user786 If the memory allocation will fail then the pointer a[0] get the value NULL and the address of the previously allocated memory will be lost.

Comment: Let me add some more problems to the ones discussed. If malloc functions are used, it would be better to check what they return: https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/0938/ Another unsafe construct is the one like a[0] = realloc(a[0], 18). If memory is not allocated, the a[0] pointer becomes null and a memory leak occurs because the previous value of a[0] is lost: https://pvs-studio.com/en/docs/warnings/v701/